# How to convert a passed c++ long pointer to java Pointer or array

Tags: java, swing, pointers, wrapper

I have a long pointer that has been passed from c++ to java that refers to an image data, now i want to retrieve the array from this [pointer](http://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#share%28long%29) in java ,how can i do this
what i have is long ptr in java

i tried this code but i dont know how to make ptr refer to _pointer

```
long _pointer=Image.GetCptr();
com.sun.jna.Pointer ptr = new com.sun.jna.Memory(2 * 512 * 512);
short testarr[] = new short [512 * 512];
ptr.read(_pointer, testarr, 0, testarr.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [jna.java.net Documentation](http://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#read%28long,%20byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) read function has the following parameters:

```
public void read(long offset,
             byte[] buf,
             int index,
             int length)

Indirect the native pointer, copying from memory pointed to by native pointer, into the specified array.

Parameters:
    offset - byte offset from pointer into which data is copied
    buf - byte array into which data is copied
    index - array index from which to start copying
    length - number of elements from native pointer that must be copied
```

1. As you can see first parameter is `byte offset from the pointer data is copied`. in your case 0.
2. The second parameter is `byte array the data is copied`. In your case the pointer pointing to the actual image data, or _pointer.
3. The third parameter is `array index in destination` which would be 0 again.
4. and the fourth parameter number of bytes to copy which seems to be 2*512*512.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: it says that there's not a suitable method that takes int,long,int,int..that happened when i placed _pointer in the second argument :)

Comment: I really don't know anything about this API. I tried to figure it from the documentation. Sry if I wasted your time :)